# Retrieving all the columns using PFQuery

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I am using parse framework in my new application and trying to fetch data from one of it table. Parse table contains 20 columns of where nearly 15 columns are of string type. Below is code for fetching

```
PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Product"];
[query setLimit:20];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {

    for (PFObject *obj in objects) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dict setValue:obj[@"GTIN_CD"] forKey:@"GTIN_CD"];
        [dict setValue:obj[@"GTIN_NM"] forKey:@"GTIN_NM"];

        [self.arrProducts addObject:dict];  
    }

    [self.tblSearchResult setDelegate:self];
    [self.tblSearchResult setDataSource:self];
    [self.tblSearchResult reloadData];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}
}];
```

When I am trying to fetch this two object GTIN_CD, GTIN_NM, it doesn't return any value. Also object contains value of 5 columns only.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those fields really objects? (meaning pointers to other objects) If so, you have to add [query includeKey:@"GTIN_CD"]; to include them in the query.

Comment: No. They are of simple string type.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the object you fetched. You're both getting and setting value from the dict. Try this:

```
PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Product"];
[query setLimit:20];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; // Initialize outside of loop
        for (PFObject *obj in objects) {
            [dict setValue:obj[@"GTIN_CD"] forKey:@"GTIN_CD"]; // obj[@"key"] instead of dict[@"key"]
            [dict setValue:obj[@"GTIN_NM"] forKey:@"GTIN_NM"];
        }

        [self.tblSearchResult setDelegate:self];
        [self.tblSearchResult setDataSource:self];
        [self.tblSearchResult reloadData];

   }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
    }
}];
```

UPDATE

Try this inside your if(!error):

```
for (PFObject *obj in objects) {
    for (NSString *key in [obj allKeys]) {
        if([obj[key] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            NSLog(@"Key: %@ - Value: %@", key, obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

This should log all your columns and the values in them. Note that I haven't tested this code myself right now, so it may have typos etc.

Comment: I am using this values in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of UITableViewDelegate. Also I am unable to view this fields if I print objects too. So I think there is not a problem with fetching / storing in dictionary.

Comment: Your error was that you didnt use obj[@"GTIN_CD"] to get the values from the object you fetched. And your code is not setting anything into any cell. You put the values in dict, but you don't use dict anywhere. dict was declared inside the for loop, and would be lost for each iteration. I moved it outside, but it will still not help you if you don't use the contents for anything.

Comment: @Handsomeguy is right, there's a mistake in your code, where you wrote "dict" it should have been "obj", lines 7 and 8.

Comment: I had edited the code. But still I couldn't get those fields value.

Comment: Are you sure ALL Product objects have those values? And that their column names are exactly GTIN_CD etc in upper case?

Comment: I added code to log all your object's keys (column names) and values. If you have only strings, you can remove the check for NSString class. If this doesn't log any values, there are no values...